# Is there a Type to denote two 'int's in UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

I need a pair of `int`s to denote a point. But UWP's [Point](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.foundation.point.x) uses `float`s.

Is there some type of built in pair of `int`s so I don't have to create a custom one? If it's `Height` and `Width` that's fine. Just as long as it's two `int`s.

Comment: You can store ints in floats.

Comment: @DourHighArch There's a reason for strong typing a language. If there's nothing built in, I'll just create a new Type. But I would rather not reinvent the wheel.

Comment: <int, int> works if you're using c# 7.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you need is a single object with the two `int` values you can use `Tuple<int, int>`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.tuple-2.

Comment: Thanks. This is not exactly what I was looking for but is nevertheless a solution. I'll wait, though, before accepting, in case someone finds an actual class for it.